# Почему ChatMemberUpdated и ChatInviteLink, не снимает ограничения?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть такой код

```html
invite_link = await bot.create_chat_invite_link(update.chat.id)
```

создает, для каждого, постоянную пригласительную ссылку, нужно, чтобы пользователь поделился пригласительной ссылкой и только тогда, как подпишется, новый участник в группу телеграм, снимутся ограничения, в группе.

Читал документацию.

ChatJoinRequest
invite_link  ChatInviteLink.  Ссылка приглашения в чат, которая использовалась пользователем для отправки запроса на присоединение

ChatMemberUpdated
invite_link  ChatInviteLink.  Ссылка-приглашение в чат, по которой пользователь присоединился к чату; только для присоединения к мероприятиям по ссылке-приглашению.

Прописал, вот такой код, ошибок нет, но ограничения, не снимаются, при подписке, по пригласительной ссылке.

```html
@dp.chat_member_handler()
#async def chat_invite_link(update: types.ChatInviteLink):
async def chat_member_handler(update: types.ChatInviteLink):
    user_id = update.from_user.id
    username = update.from_user.username
    name = update.from_user.full_name
    chat_id = update.chat.id
    invite_link = await bot.create_chat_invite_link(update.chat.id)


    #ChatJoinRequest.invite_link = await bot.get_chat_member(chat_id=update.chat.id, user_id=update.from_user.id)
    ChatMemberUpdated.invite_link = await bot.get_chat_member(chat_id=update.chat.id, user_id=update.from_user.id)

    if invite_link in ChatMemberUpdated.invite_link:
        user_id = update.from_user.id
        chat_id = update.chat.invite_link

        #if not db.user_exists(user_id, chat_id):
            #db.add_user(user_id, chat_id, name, username, invite_link)
        #db.user_added_new_user(user_id, chat_id)
        if db.check_new_users(user_id, chat_id):
            await bot.restrict_chat_member(chat_id=chat_id, user_id=user_id, permissions=types.ChatPermissions(can_send_messages=True, can_send_media_messages=True, can_send_other_messages=True, can_add_web_page_previews=True, can_send_polls=True, can_pin_messages=True, can_invite_users=True, can_change_info=True, until_date=None))
            return




@dp.chat_join_request_handler()
async def join_request(update: types.ChatInviteLink):
    user_id = update.from_user.id
    username = update.from_user.username
    name = update.from_user.full_name
    chat_id = update.chat.id
    invite_link = await bot.create_chat_invite_link(update.chat.id)

    ChatJoinRequest.invite_link = await bot.get_chat_member(chat_id=update.chat.id, user_id=update.from_user.id)

    if invite_link in ChatJoinRequest.invite_link:
        user_id = update.from_user.id
        chat_id = update.chat.invite_link

        await bot.restrict_chat_member(chat_id=chat_id, user_id=user_id, permissions=types.ChatPermissions(can_send_messages=True, can_send_media_messages=True, can_send_other_messages=True, can_add_web_page_previews=True, can_send_polls=True, can_pin_messages=True, can_invite_users=True, can_change_info=True, until_date=None))
        return

def register_handlers_client(dp: Dispatcher):
    dp.register_message_handler(get_handler, content_types=['photo', 'text'], state=FSMReport.photo)
    dp.register_message_handler(get_handler, content_types=['video', 'text'], state=FSMReport.video)
    dp.chat_member_handlers(get_handler, content_types=['photo', 'video', 'text'])
    dp.chat_member_handlers(chat_member_handler, types.ChatInviteLink, content_types=['photo', 'video', 'text'])
    dp.chat_join_request_handlers(join_request, types.ChatInviteLink, content_types=['photo', 'video', 'text'])
    dp.register_chat_join_request_handler(join_request, types.ChatInviteLink, content_types=['photo', 'video', 'text'])
    dp.register_chat_member_handler(chat_member_handler, types.ChatMemberUpdated, content_types=['photo', 'video', 'text'])
```